# How to do math operations in python with asyncio (parallel/multiprocessing)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I have a very simple script on python 3.7 and don't understand why it executes consistently, not simultaneously. Where is mistake? This is very important to stay script structure as it is, meaning don't remove class and semaphore, and **I need to compute math operations** in `op()`. I tried to play with `self.op()`, removing `async`, but the same results.

```
import time
import asyncio


class Trader:

    def __init__(self, ticker):
        self.ticker = ticker

    async def _init(self):
        # asyncio.run(self.op())
        await self.op()
        print('{} ended'.format(self.ticker))

    async def op(self):
        a = range(1000000) 
        b = [] 
        for i in a:
            b.append(i*2)


async def fetch_tickers():
    return await asyncio.gather(*(asyncio.ensure_future(safe_trader(ticker)) for ticker in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']))

async def safe_trader(ticker):
    async with sem:
        t = Trader(ticker)
        return await t._init()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    results = loop.run_until_complete(fetch_tickers())
    print("%.2f execution seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Result:

```
A ended
B ended
C ended
D ended
E ended
F ended
G ended
0.82 execution seconds
```

If I leave only 1 ticker `A`, then we have results:

```
A ended
0.12 execution seconds
```

Comment: asyncio does not make things execute in parallel. It is even *more* fundamentally non-parallel than the CPython global interpreter lock - the GIL could theoretically be removed, but non-parallel execution is fundamental to the asyncio event loop model.

Comment: asyncio's use case is I/O. That's why it's named after asynchronous I/O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly in async as it's supposed to be.
Since each task requires the same amount of time and computational power to complete and in op it is not waiting for any task to complete it so executes consistently.

try with this

```
async def op(self):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

This time it will execute simultaneously as there is no computation required and system is free to give resources.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The problem is that I need (!) to make computations, in real script I need to make math operations. How to solve this?

Comment: You don't need to use asynchronous if you are only doing mathematical computational tasks.
Asynchronous only should be used if your code is waiting for some task to be completed and resource is free. In mathematical situations, resources are not free. But if you're making an HTTP or TCP calls on the network the resources are actually free while waiting for the response from the client. In your code will be able to advantage of asyncio. @sirjay